# Google Coral Dev Board PWM can't properly working at frequency higher than 100kHz

Tags: python-3.x, google-coral

I am using Coral Dev Board from Google to generate PWM signals. Programming is based on python-periphery. I managed to generate PWM signals with arbitrary frequencies and duty-cycles. But the PWM signal distorted at frequencies higher than 100kHz, either due to low sourcing current of the PWM module or huge capacitance on the pin-out, or any other reasons.

```
from periphery import PWM
# Open PWM channel
pwm1 = PWM(0, 0)
# Set frequency to 1 kHz
pwm1.frequency = 1e3
# Set duty cycle to 50%
pwm1.duty_cycle = 0.5
pwm1.enable()
```

[Waveform can be found here. The speed of the PWM signal's rising is somehow very slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkmOD.jpg)

I wonder if I need to enable some power consumption settings of the Dev Board in order to let it sourcing higher current?

Comment: You probably need a dedicated servo controller. Rpi have the same issue

Comment: By pwmq you mean pwm1 I believe.

Comment: @Manoj Yes, you are right! pwmq should be pwm1, it is a typo.